# How to style background image and overlay content above

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set the background image NOT using CSS. How can I set it in the HTML doc while having the content display over top of the image?

I want the image to be responsive with a browser width change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Rapid Weather</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <img src="images/sunny.png" alt="sunny picture" class="img">
    <section id = "weather-wrapper" class = "container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <div id = "weather-info">
            <span id = "temperature"></span><span id="unit">&#176;C</span><br><br>
            <p id = "city"></p>
            <p id = "climate"></p>
            <img id = "icon" />
          </div>
          <div id="error-info">
            <h1><span class="fa fa-warning"></span><span id="err-msg"> City not found</span></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I set the image now the content is under the image and I cant get the image to go behind the displaying script. I cant use the body selector in the CSS because it changes the rest of the content being displayed.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Mogra|Lobster|Josefin+Sans');

body {
    color: #ffffff;
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #616161;
  transition: linear 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fafafa;
}

#weather-wrapper, #error-info {
  transform: translateY(80px);
  text-align: center;
}

#temperature-wrapper {
  border: solid 1px #212121;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#error-info, #weather-info {
  display: none;
}

#title {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

#search, #weather-info {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#city, #temperature, #search input, #unit, #climate, #err-msg {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

#city, #climate {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#temperature,  #unit {
  font-size: 40px;
}

#search {
  position: relative;
}

#search input {
  text-indent: 30px;
  height: 50px !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}

#search .fa-search {
  color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 17px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#unit {
  transition: linear 0.2s;
}
#unit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ff4436;
}
```

Comment: I think you can insert a negative z-index on the imagem.

Comment: tried that and it didnt seem to work

Comment: I assume images/sunny.png is the faux background image?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `background` CSS property? Think about the semantic of your code for accessibility too. If you have an image that should be a background then it should be a background and not an image tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick and dirty

Add an `id="bg-image"` attribute to the img tag in question and apply the following CSS:

```css
img#bg-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The crucial part is that `#bg-image` is assigned a `position` property since `z-index` is only applied to elements that have `position` set.

### The right way

You should consider either setting a `background-image` attribute on the container via JS or dynamically add a `class` to the container element via JS. I.e.:

`<section id="weather-wrapper" class="container-fluid">` would become `<section id="weather-wrapper" class="container-fluid sunny">`) if it is sunny at the location in question. The background image would be predefined in CSS accordingly, i.e.

```css
#weather-wrapper.sunny {
    background-image: url(images/sunny.png);
}

#weather-wrapper.rainy {
    background-image: url(images/rainy.png);
}

/* etc. */
```

Answer (score 0):

To center it, have a look here: [CSS Styling Images](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_images.asp)

To have the image in the backgroud, you can give a positive z-index to the other elements. That may work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're objecting to using CSS for the background image. Doing so would not only solve the problem but also allow you to scale the background image so that it always fits neatly for all viewport sizes (see: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

However, since you specified a non-css solution for the background please see the following example where I have absolutely positioned the `#weather-wrapper`.

```css
body {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
}

#weather-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 10px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://baconmockup.com/800/800" alt="placeholder" class="img" width="100%">
<section id="weather-wrapper" class="container-fluid">
  This element is positioned absolutely
</section>
```

Assuming you can get over the 'without CSS' clause you could simply do it as follows. By setting the background-image within the style attribute of the `html` (so that it can be set dynamically/per-page) and having the remaining styles needed to make this a responsive background separated into the stylesheet. EG:

```css
html { 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#weather-wrapper {
/* temp styles so we can see this elemennt in the snippet */
border:10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="background-image:url('https://baconmockup.com/600/800')">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Rapid Weather</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id = "weather-wrapper" class = "container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <div id = "weather-info">
            <span id = "temperature"></span><span id="unit">&#176;C</span><br><br>
            <p id = "city"></p>
            <p id = "climate"></p>
            <img id = "icon" />
          </div>
          <div id="error-info">
            <h1><span class="fa fa-warning"></span><span id="err-msg"> City not found</span></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have multiple different HTMl pages loading depending on the weather, the pages need to have different background images based off the current weather

Comment: @curiousSloth Okay. Why does that prevent you from using CSS for it?

Comment: @curiousSloth I've extended my answer to show how you can have a per-page background without having to mess about with absolute positioning or a className per image (as per the accepted answer)